# Using blockchain info from wallet in code

Tags: batch-file, blockchain, bitcoin

I have a crypto wallet that is synced with the network that has the current block height the amount of coins difficulty, status(locked, unlocked) etc information I need. I would like to program a batch file that looks at the current block height and executes commands to the wallet if that height matches what I am looking for.

Is this possible I know the wallets debug menu has these capabilities but can I do this from a command line?

Comment: You'd have to check the wallet's documentation page.